(Tabularray) how do i make it so that a \linewidth setup has indentation spacing on both sides?
I have the following code that is tblr code that has tables being indented and causing my desired \linewidth result to not be achieved
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Fat

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
  width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
}
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Multirow Cell & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Multicolumn Cell \\
  & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
  Row 2 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
\end{tblr}


\end{document}

The table is spaced exactly like they were text, as the left side is correct, but the right side isn't exactly like the left side. it goes over and doesn't stop at how the indented side does
is there a way to fix this? i would greatly appreciate any help given with tabularray

Add \noindent before \begin{tblr}

Perhaps this is what are you trying to achieve.
Of course if you want your tblr to span the complete linewidth you can use \noindent just before your \begin{tblr} to avoid adding the parindent to the tblr.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\tblrwidth}
\setlength{\tblrwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\parindent}


Fat

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
  width = \tblrwidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
}
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Multirow Cell & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Multicolumn Cell \\
  & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
  Row 2 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
\end{tblr}


\end{document}

